# Response в аргумент

Tags: python, json, response

```
result2 = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/trades/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxi').json
r.text
print(r.text)
```

Response:

> {"success":true,"trades":[{"dir":"in","trade_id":"3665127078","bot_id":"915458917"

`trade_id` необходимо поместить сюда:

```
client.accept_trade_offer()
```

Как это можно сделать?)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете распарсить Ваш ответ с помощью модуля `json`.

***Пример:***

```py
import json


# Я добавил 3 символа в конце, чтобы это стало валидным Json...
response = '{"success":true,"trades":[{"dir":"in","trade_id":"3665127078","bot_id":"915458917"}]}'
d = json.loads(response)

trade_id = d['trades'][0]['trade_id']
print(trade_id)
```

***stdout:***

```html
3665127078
```

Comment: Ты не правильно понял.Я делаю реквестс и получаю этот респонс